# Eventos en lista de botones por separado en ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic4

Hola soy nuevo en la programación espero que me puedan ayudar, estoy tratando de hacer una app en ionic 4 y necesito saber como puedo hacer para que se incremente el valor de un solo item al presionar en un boton generado con ngFor, ya que ahora al presionar en uno se incrementa en todos a la vez.
este es mi código en HTML donde estoy generando los items.

```
introducir el código aquí
    <ion-list>
          <ion-item *ngFor="let producto of productos">
           <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
            <ion-img [src]="[producto.urlImagen]"></ion-img>
           </ion-thumbnail>
          <ion-label>
           <h3>{{producto.nombre}}</h3>
           <p>Precio: ${{producto.precio}}</p>
           <p>Stock: {{producto.stock}} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
          </ion-label>
       <ion-item>
         <ion-button shape="round" *ngIf="a" >-</ion-button> <ion-label *ngIf="a">{{cantidad}}</ion- 
          label><ion-button shape="round" (click) = "select(producto.id)">+</ion-button>
       </ion-item>
      </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
```

Este es el método para incrementar

```
    select(idProducto) {
      this.cantidad = ++this.cantidad;
      if (this.cantidad === 0) {
        this.a = false;
      } else {
        this.a = true;
      }
    }
```

la variable "a" es solo para mostrar el contador.
E buscado manejo de eventos por todo lado ya que creo que eso me ayudaría pero no encuentro algo que me ayude en este lío en el que estoy.

así es como sale en la app.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es simple,  estas usando una sola propiedad para todos tus botones,  y esa propiedad se llama cantidad:

```
<ion-button shape="round" *ngIf="a" >-</ion-button> <ion-label *ngIf="a">{{cantidad}}
```

Esa es la parte en tu codigo donde usas la propiedad `cantidad`, sin embargo,  ¿No deberias tener una propiedad cantidad en tu arreglo de entradas por cada objeto que tengas?, es decir,  no deberia ser mas bien algo como:

```
{{producto.cantidad}}
```

A eso se debe el inconveniente,  ojo, si no tienes una propiedad cantidad en tus objetos,  si o si deberas agregarla en cada uno de ellos de lo contrario si apuntas a una sola variable, obviamente tambien se cambiaria en los otros elementos que la estuviesen usando.